# CartoDB only georeferences half of my table

Tags: carto, geocoding

I imported a CSV file into CartoDB, with over a million points, all with a clear (and correct) latitude and longitude. For many of the collected data points the georeference column says ‘null’, while the latitude & longitude are correct.

So CartoDB only georeferenced half of my table and I am missing a lot of points.

I do have a payed account and did not reach my maximum of points I can georeference.

Anybody know how I can get my whole CSV georeferenced?

Comment: A similar question got asked at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132088/cartodb-only-georeferences-half-of-my-table, and the same advice about posting samples that didn't work might be useful for your scenario too.

Comment: @BradHards The link you gave seems to be to this question.

Comment: Well that was very similar, but obviously not too helpful. Perhaps http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88383/cartodb-geocoding-not-working?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I'd check out the options you have for georeferencing your data:

http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-editor.html#geocoding-data

In your case, you can specify which column is latitude and which is longitude if the importer doesn't guess them on import (see the first image in the link above).